# What is considered as a better way to keep unstaged changes: "git stash" or "git diff to a patch file"?

Tags: git

```
[gdaniel@vnc23 sx_fit_regression]$ git status
# On branch master
# Changed but not updated:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
#   (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
#
#       modified:   eth/utilities/eth_constants.py
#       modified:   eth/utilities/eth_fdb_tools.py
#       modified:   libs/tools/string_manipulation_tools.py
#
# Untracked files:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
#
#       .project
#       .pydevproject
#       eth/fdb/configuration/
no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
[gdaniel@vnc23 sx_fit_regression]$

[gdaniel@vnc23 sx_fit_regression]$ git fetch origin master
From file:///mswg/git/switchx/sx_fit_regression
 * branch            master     -> FETCH_HEAD

[gdaniel@vnc23 sx_fit_regression]$ git rebase --merge FETCH_HEAD
cannot rebase: you have unstaged changes
M       eth/utilities/eth_constants.py
M       eth/utilities/eth_fdb_tools.py
M       libs/tools/string_manipulation_tools.py
[gdaniel@vnc23 sx_fit_regression]$
```

As you can see, I can`t rebase, because I have unstaged changes.

Suppose I need to push the above code changes into GIT.

As far as I know, this is the flow:

```
"Code Review -> commit -> fetch -> rebase -> push"
```

Suppose I can`t have code review in the given week for the above 3 files...And I would like to continue working on other 2 files which require code modifications and can have code review for these 2 files today.

For this to happen, I need to keep the changes for the 3 files.

1. What is better: "git stash" or "git diff to a patch file"

> git diff HEAD~..HEAD filename > fileA.patch

2. How do I stash the 3 files separately?

Thanks,

Qwerty

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your input. If I keep the patch files outside the GIT repository, then it won`t pollute anything.Can you please show (code example) how to stash each file separately? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, creating a stash will always save the whole state at once. You can however use the patch functionality to interactively select what changes you want to be stashed. To do that, simply call it with `--patch` or `-p` in short.

As for comparison with patches, you need to consider that stashes are the built-in solution to “put away” the current state and clear up the working directory so you temporarily can work on something else. It might seem more intuitive to use patches if you are used to them but usually you don’t need to the process manually and can just use Git’s mechanisms instead.

Using stashes has the benefit, that since stashes are just like commits, Git also stores metadata like the author, date, and a message. Most importantly though, it also includes a pointer to the parent commit, so when you apply the stash later, it can calculate the diff and also *automatically merge* the stash with any changes that might have happened in between. When using patches, you would have to resolve any issue manually.

Answer (score 2):

Just commit your 3 files to a new branch. Branches are cheap.

```
git checkout -b branch-3-files
git commit -a
git checkout master
git pull
... work on other 2 files ...
git commit
git push
... review original 3 files ...
git merge branch-3-files
git push
```

Comment: There’s practically no difference between stashing and using a separate branch. Stashes use commits internally.

Comment: Yes, but a branch has a more clear name, and the commit has a relevant message.

Comment: You can name stashes too.

Comment: One point that should be made is that branches are not just cheap, they are honest: Stashing, and any other rebase operation effectively lies about history. The truth is, that development has diverged, and that it needs to be merged back to get back to a unified state. `git stash` and `git rebase` hide this truth, which has negative consequences from time to time.

Comment: I've just played with creating multiple stashes with messages. The log looks bloody confusing. Although I've saved 3 stashes, only one is visible at the tip. Where are the others?